# not able to remove mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying out this command to completely remove mysql from an aws instance `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql*
```

But it's throwing all kinds of errors:

```
// important ones:

Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--remove):
installed mysql-server-8.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

and then at the end:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-8.0
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when I type out:

```
whereis mysql
```

I see:

```
mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
```

So it's not completely removed.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the command "service mysql" (no need for sudo to do this) which will give you a list of options mysql accepts. This way you can check if it is still running and then stop it, before again trying to remove it.

Comment: mysql is a server so you need to STOP it before you try and remove it. On my setup this command does it `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown`

Comment: @darth_epoxy @Gyro Gearloose I cannot. I get this: `Unit mysql.service could not be found.`

Comment: Hmm looks like it broke installing or broke un-installing. Try and re-install it and/or repaitrthe package. Then stop the service and try and remove it with `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*`

Comment: @darth_epoxy tried that already. it was still the same. Never mind. I just terminated the instance and created a fresh one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command: `sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql` to find any mysql pacakges installed then remove them `sudo apt --purge autoremove package_name`. You can then try to reinstall it